# Objection.js Eager is missing FROM clause

Tags: javascript, sql, postgresql, objection.js

I am using objection js for PostGres and I try to find a payments with gift status of 'Closed' but i keep getting eror:

> missing FROM-clause entry for table

Below is my query.

```
const payments = await GiftPayments.query()
        .eager('gift.[detail, status]')
        .where('gift.status.name', 'Closed')
        .orderBy('gift.id');
```

I also tried modifyEager like below and suddenly the status field just becomes null.

```
const payments = await GiftPayments.query()
            .eager('gift.[detail, status]')
            .modifyEager('gift', builder => 
                {builder.where('name', '=', 'Closed')
             })
            .orderBy('gift.id');
```

Thank you so much in advance!!

Comment: Can you give us any details about GiftPayments() ? It seems that the table "gift" is not in it or is aliased to something other than "gift".

Comment: @JoeLove yes you are right. This payment is BelongsToOneRelation to Gift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the table "gift" is not in GiftPayments() or is aliased to something other than "gift".